# 'Keep Both' or 'Replace' during xcode 6 GM installation

Tags: ios, xcode

While copying Xcode 6 GM to the Applications folder I had options to 'Keep Both' or 'Replace'. I would like to confirm a few things before installing. 
If I choose the option to 'Keep Both' will I be able to run Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 independently without any issues? 
If I choose 'Replace' is there a way I could possibly return to Xcode 5?

Comment: 'Keep Both' will result 2 Xcodes (Xcode 5.x and XCode 6) in application folder and you can run either . Replacing will remove Xcode 5 and will install XCode 6. You will only be able to use XCode 6 than

Answer (score 1):

If you choose Replace, you will be able to run Xcode 6 without any problem. And you should be able to install later Xcode 5 and run both in case you needed. If you choose Keep both, you should be able to run both without any problem. I chose replace and there were no problem at all. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Keep both or replace will not break anything. Pros of accepting keep both is that you will be able to test your app on ios 6.1 simulator and even ios 6.0 simulator, if you still need to support it.